# how to implement server for generating tokens for video chat -- vidyo.io

Tags: android, server, vidyo

I was using https://vidyocreatetoken.appspot.com/ for generating token and by html parsing i get the token inside app just to check my app is working fine.

[image]

But now i  have to implement server for generating tokens and i don't know much about this, can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to signal to the backend of your application via an HTTP GET or POST to generate a token and then pass it back to your client application where it can be used to connect to a call.